# Most efficient way to reflect changes in bookmarklet development?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

**Current situation**

I'm developing a bookmarklet by using a stub as the actual bookmark that sources JavaScript code in a file on GitHub. I test the bookmarklet on a webpage and then I make changes to the JavaScript code in a text editor, push it to the GitHub file with git on the command line, and then run the bookmarklet again on the web page.

**Problems with current situation**

- This approach seems tedious to me. Every time I make a change to the JS code in the text editor I have to save in the text editor and write 3 commands (git add, git commit, git push) to update the changes in the GitHub file (and then click the bookmarklet again).
- What's more frustrating is that it seems like Chrome takes a very long time to recognize the changes in a recently changed GitHub file. I test this by making a simple `alert("message");` command, changing the `message` value, pushing the changed code to GitHub (successfully), and seeing if the bookmarklet stub sources the recently changed file (it doesn't).

I avoid caching by appending a random number to the GitHub file URL sourced by the stub - stub shown below:

```
javascript:(function(){
    var script=document.createElement('script');
    script.type='text/javascript';
    script.src='https://rawgit.com/username/repo_name/master/bookmarklet.js?v='+(Math.random()*1000);
    document.body.appendChild(script);})();
```

**Question**

Is there a better way to develop bookmarklets where you can quickly see changes in bookmarklet code when the bookmarklet is used? Or can anyone see any problems in what I'm doing?

Thanks!

Comment: You might try simply paste `bookrmarlet.js` source to the browser console.

Comment: I don't think this will work. Dragging `javascript:(function(){
 alert('hi');
})();` into Chrome just turns the page blank. Additionally, in order for the bookmarklet to work like it should, interacting with the current page's content, I think the code or a stub sourcing the code needs to be in bookmark form.